# Django deployment with Docker on EB failed and 502 badgateway

Tags: django, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./config/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0:8000
        ports:
            - '8000:8000'
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres_test
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_test_pw

    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
            - '6379:6379'
```

and in vscode terminal

eb init -> choose docker , Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2

eb create -> application balancer type

and when "eb open" i got 502 badgateway

what should i do

Answer (score 1):

By default, EB looks for app running on PORT 8080. You can configure it to the port of your choosing. - Open the Elastic Beanstalk console, and in the Regions list, select your AWS Region.

- In the navigation pane, choose Environments, and then choose the name of your environment from the list.
- In the navigation pane, choose Configuration.
- In the Software configuration category, choose Edit.
- Looks for "Environment properties".
- Add property name as "PORT" and value as "8000"
- Apply the changes.